# Convergence of integral $I=\int_0^\infty \frac{t^{\frac{\alpha-n+1}{n}}}{e^t} dt$

Tags: integration, convergence-divergence, definite-integrals

For which $\alpha\in\mathbb{R}$  the integral $I=\int_0^\infty \frac{t^{\frac{\alpha-n+1}{n}}}{e^t} dt$ converges?

I tried to write I as sum of two integrals, from 0 to 1 and from 1 to $\infty$:

$I=\int_0^1 \frac{t^{\frac{\alpha-n+1}{n}}}{e^t} dt+\int_1^\infty \frac{t^{\frac{\alpha-n+1}{n}}}{e^t} dt$.

The first itegral converges for $\alpha>n-1$ and the second integral behaves as $\int_1^\infty \frac{dt}{t^\frac{n-1-\alpha}{n}e^t}$ which converges by integral criterion for $n-1-\alpha>n$ or for $\alpha<-1$.

Therefore, integral diverges for every $\alpha\in R$.

Is my solution correct? Any help is welcome. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Do we have $n>0$? What is the range of $n$?

Comment: @OlivierOloa Yes, $n>0$.

Comment: $\displaystyle\Re\left[\left(\alpha +1\right)n\right] > 0$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We assume $n>0$.

**Hint**. As $t\to 0^+$,
$$
\frac{t^{\frac{\alpha-n+1}{n}}}{e^t}\sim t^{\frac{\alpha-n+1}{n}}
$$ giving that $\displaystyle\int_0^1 \frac{t^{\frac{\alpha-n+1}{n}}}{e^t} dt$ is convergent if and only if $-\frac{\alpha-n+1}{n}<1$, that is *if and only if*
$$\alpha>-1.$$

As $t\to \infty$,
$$
\frac{t^{\frac{\alpha-n+1}{n}}}{e^{\frac t2}}\to 0
$$ giving that $\displaystyle\int_1^\infty \frac{t^{\frac{\alpha-n+1}{n}}}{e^t}\: dt=\int_1^\infty \frac{t^{\frac{\alpha-n+1}{n}}}{e^{\frac t2}}\:\frac{1}{e^{\frac t2}}\: dt$ is convergent no matter what the value of $\alpha$ is.

Answer (score 1):

$$\int_0^∞ t^{\frac{(a+1)}{n} -1} e^{-t} dt= \Gamma{(\dfrac{a+1}{n})}$$
For convergence $∞>\dfrac{a+1}{n}>0$

Means $-1<a<∞ $ and $ 0<n<∞ $